Movie in which an asteroid landed on Earth and gave a lady super powers when she touched it
What's the name of the movie where an asteroid landed on Earth, small though, and a lady with her boyfriend went to check it out. The lady touched it and it gave her super powers; her hair also became white and I think her teeth changed. New one came too.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you watch this?

"New one came too"?

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Incorrect answers are an excellent chance to [edit] new details in, e.g.  "I know that it isn't Rocks to Riches because the boyfriend had only one arm and the girl was Polynesian."

I think "new one came too" means that one or more missing teeth grew back?

If it was animated, could be 2009's Monsters vs. Aliens. The brunette Susan Murphy is hit by a meteorite



that ends up turning her into a 50 foot tall giant in the middle of her wedding, with her hair color changing to white as it does so.



Nothing changes about her teeth, though, aside from them getting bigger along with the rest of her.

It's not a small meteorite, but I think you are thinking of the scene from My Super Ex-Girlfriend

Professor Bedlam was formerly Jenny's high school boyfriend, Barry Lambert. While about to become intimate they were interrupted by the crash of the meteor. He saw her obtain superpowers, then watched and became embittered as she ignored him for other guys, something her new charisma made possible. Consequently, he studied to be a supervillain and is now G-Girl's nemesis.

Her braces pop off as her teeth become perfect, and her hair does go from a mousy brown to blonde.
 
Transformation scene



Later in the film, someone else gains the same powers.

 Both Hannah and Jenny are catapulted off the roof, apparently to their deaths; Jenny appears within seconds, powers restored, threatening even more mayhem. Hannah unexpectedly reappears, having also been exposed to the meteorite and gained the same powers as G-Girl. She saves Matt, and the second fight between Hannah and Jenny is a full-on super-brawl, destroying part of the neighboring properties.

